# node.js append string to XML

Tags: node.js

I have XML and PDF files in a given path.  Both XML and PDF files will be named the same.  Need code that will open each XML in the given path and append 2 elements.  One is the path to corresponding PDF and the other is the filename of the corresponding PDF.  Below is some code I started with.  But, I am new to this and appreciate the help.

```
function test(){
var v = new  XMLWriter('UTF-8', '1.0');
v.writeStartDocument(true);
v.writeElementString('test','Hello World');
v.writeEndDocument();
console.log( v.flush() );
}
test();
```

Thank you!